# Angular add modules after angular.bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, meteor

I'm using meteor + angular. My intention is to add more dependencies after the app bootstrap (This is because the package is the one handling the bootstrapping at the start and I don't have much control of it). Now while doing that, I would also want to enforce a basic code structure wherein for example, I would compile all controllers in one module.

Here's the basic idea:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app.controllers', [])

    .controller('MainCtrl', function() {
        // ...
    })

    .controller('SubCtrl', function() {
        // ...
    })

    .controller('AnotherCtrl', function() {
        // ...
    });
```

Then include that to the main module as dependency:

```
angular.module('app', [
    'app.filters',
    'app.services',
    'app.directives',
    'app.controllers' // Here
]);
```

After some research, I've discovered that what I'm trying to do (Adding dependencies after bootstrap) is actually a part of a feature request to the angular team. So my option is using, for example,  `$controllerProvider` and `register()` function:

```
Meteor.config(function($controllerProvider) {
    $controllerProvider.register('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
        // ...
    });
});

Meteor.config(function($controllerProvider) {
    $controllerProvider.register('SubCtrl', function($scope) {
        // ...
    });
});

Meteor.config(function($controllerProvider) {
    $controllerProvider.register('AnotherCtrl', function($scope) {
        // ...
    });
});
```

It's works though not that elegant. The questions are:

- What's a more elegant way of doing the `config` and `register` part?
- Is there a way to register a module instead?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/w0ZEBz02l8s/YK3H0eMmlxcJ

Answer (score 11):

Create your module:

```
angular.module('app.controllers', []);
```

Add it as a dependency:

```
angular.module('app').requires.push('app.controllers');
```

Comment: can you provide demo for this solution? e.g. on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: According to my understanding, doing angular.module('app').requires.push('app.controllers'); will simply add 'app.controllers' to the array of requires within the app. This does not invoke or notify angular of the new requirement. What code would you use after this to load notify angular.
I tried angular.module('app').run() and event $rootScope.$digest() but doesn't work.
Thanks.

Comment: I am facing a similar issue.. any solution ??

Comment: This will not work after bootstrap, only if the code is executed before the page's ready event is fired and bootstrap is started.

Answer (score 1):

according to [this presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/nirkaufman/angularjs-lazy-loading-techniques) (slide 12) you can assign `controllerProvider` to app.

**Example of replacing module's `controller` method**: http://jsfiddle.net/arzo/HB7LU/6659/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

//note overriding controller method might be a little controversial :D 
myApp.config(function allowRegisteringControllersInRuntime($controllerProvider) {
    var backup = myApp.controller;
    myApp.controller = $controllerProvider.register;
    myApp.controller.legacy = backup;
})

myApp.run(function ($rootScope, $compile) {

    myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.name = 'Superhero';
    })

    var elem;
    var scope=$rootScope;
    elem = $compile('<p ng-controller="MyCtrl">{{name}}</br><input ng-model="name" /></p>')($rootScope, function (clonedElement, scope) {
        console.log('newly created element', clonedElement[0])
        document.body.appendChild(clonedElement[0]);
    });
    console.log('You can access original register via', myApp.controller.legacy);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The only method that I've seen that works is replacing the `angular.module` function with your own function returning the module you used to bootstrap your app.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);    
angular.module = function() {
    return myApp;
}
```

So that all modules that are registered afterwards are actually being registered in your `myApp` module.

This method combined with the one you describe in the question (using providers like `$controllerProvider`) will allow you to add "modules" after `angular.bootstrap`.

**Demo**

See this jsfiddle for a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/josketres/aw3L38r4/

**Drawbacks**

- The `config` blocks of the modules that are added after `angular.bootstrap` will not be called. Maybe there's a way to fix this, but I haven't found it.
- Overriding `angular.module` feels like a "dirty hack".

Comment: Source: http://pinkieguy.com/post/101949656975/loading-module-dependencies-in-angular-after