# Loading Module After Angular Bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, lazy-loading, angularjs-module, angularjs-injector

I am trying to load and inject a module after app bootstrap. For example let's say my initial module is:

```
angular.module('mainApp', []);
```

Later on I realize the user needs all of the routes available via `secondaryApp` to open up to them.  So  now I need my module to look something like this:

```
angular.module('mainApp', ['secondaryApp']);
```

I am successfully lazyLoading the secondaryApp js file, but I cannot add it to the mainApp.  I have tried adding it to the requires array, i.e.

```
var app = angular.module('mainApp');
app.requires[app.requires.length] = 'secondaryApp';
```

This adds the module name to the requires array but the `mainApp` still does not have access to the routes/states provided in the `secondaryApp`.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I have been stuck on this one for a while now.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular add modules after angular.bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21568075/angular-add-modules-after-angular-bootstrap)

Comment: The post you link to mentions trying pushing new dependency to requires array as the solution, this is not the solution, I'm hoping to drum up some new answers

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, you can't define `angular.module('mainApp', []);` more than once.

Every time you declare a module with dependencies as so, it overrides the prior declaration.